# powershell Test-Path is not recognized as a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, runtime-error, scheduled-tasks

As a follow up to my question [powershell if-else does not follow either branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245993/powershell-if-else-does-not-follow-either-branch) I've found another odd situation.  I have a script that is running as a scheduled task once a day.  The problem occurs only when run as a scheduled task (never from a command prompt, ide, or powershell window) and even then only on some days. The relevant code is

```
$target_dir = "\\server\path\"
$tmpStatus = "init"
$err = $false
try { $tmpStatus = Test-Path ( $target_dir + "receivals.tmp") }
catch
{
    $tmpStatus = $error | foreach { $_.Exception }
    $err = $true
}
```

Some days $tmpStatus reports the problem

```
System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term 'Test-Path' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
   at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
```

However, later on in the same script on the same run when I use Test-Path again, it works just fine every time.  How can Test-Path not be a valid command?

Comment: started happening in my build system today.

Comment: @ranomore is yours running as a scheduled task, or interactive or some other way? Can you reproduce the error reliably?

Comment: Wish I'd seen your note sooner. I rebooted the machine where this had started happening and the problem disappeared. But it was running in a non-interactive process through TeamCity. I tried various refactorings of the script but the error persisted.

Comment: Mine seems unrelated to server reboots. Though the reboot is 17 hours before the next script schedule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with qualifier:

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Test-Path ( $target_dir + "receivals.tmp")
```

Comment: ok that has been working for just over a month now, when the previous success streak max was about 1 week. Why do you think this works while just using `Test-Path` does not?

Comment: The module '!Microsoft.PowerShell.Management' could not be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I added this to my build scripts.

```
Import-Module "$env:SystemRoot\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management.psd1"
```